# Click on a link using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'd like to click on the following link but it's not working:

```
<ul class="pagination pagination-large">
  <li style="display:inline;">
    <a name="Next" href="jamm/flavours/page=2" class="next">
      <span class="icon-navigate_next"></span>
    </a>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

My code

```
items = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class = 'pagination pagination-large']//li[@style ='display:inline;']")
print items
for k in items:
    print k
    k.click()
    print("clicked")
    k.send_keys(webdriver.common.keys.Keys.SPACE)
```

Comment: Share exception. Also share page URL if it's a public page

Comment: It simply passes does not click and its not a public page

Comment: Did you try to click *link* (`<a>...</a>`)?

Comment: yep I have tried everything

Comment: Accepted answer tells us that you haven't really *tried everything* as search by link `@name`/`@class` is the first thing you should have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the `xpath` you are using is not finding the element you need, in fact, it targets the list element, not the anchor.

Maybe you can try to identify the link by using the css class `next` instead:

```
items = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('next')
for item in items:
    item.click()
```

If it works now, you can either just use that if you don't have any other elements using it or you can fix your `xpath`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
browser.find_elements_by_name('Next')
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.